# Special Pop Up View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, swift2

I am currently building a shopping list program, and need some advice.  When I currently add a new object, it covers the entire screen, even on the iPad.  But I saw this design that I really like, but don't know how to complete.

[View Controller on top of another in the center of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu4NU.jpg)

I would like to do what this person did, but need some help completing it.  I currently am programming only in Swift 2.3, because of a stale computer, and would rather an example in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set the `modalPresentationStyle` of the view controller you are presenting to `formSheet` (whatever the Swift 2.3 name of that is). Then present it as your normally would with `presentViewController...`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked perfectly!  And in Swift 2.3, the formSheet is named the same as Swift 3.0